# How to calculate outliers by columns in R?

Tags: r

My code

```
dat <- read.csv("numeric.csv")
dat1 <- na.omit(dat)

##Function to calculate outliers
FindOutliers <- function(data) {
  lowerq = quantile(data)[2]
  upperq = quantile(data)[4]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq #Or use IQR(data)
  # we identify extreme outliers
  extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
  extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)
  result <- which(data > extreme.threshold.upper | data < extreme.threshold.lower)
}


out_dat <- names(dat1)
out_dat <- as.data.frame(out_dat)

for (dat in seq_along(dat1)){
  temp <- FindOutliers(dat)
  out_dat$outlier_count <- length(temp)
}
```

I am able to get outliers if am passing each column individually but by passing the entire dataframe , i am unable to reproduce the same result.

Sample dataset

```
df <- read.table(text = "
    var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 var6 var7
a      1    1   10   10    1    1    1
b     10    1    1    1    1    1    851
c      1    1    1    1    1    1    158
d      1    1011    1    1    1    5    1
e      1    1    55    1    9    1    1
f      1    1    1    1    1    781    1
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get position index of outliers (per column):

```
pos <- lapply(df, FindOutliers)
```

To get number of outliers (per column):

```
lengths(pos)
```

It is not a good idea to work with small sample size. Say, with your example `df` with sample size 6, only 851 is detected as an outlier in the last column, and 158 is not picked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with apply.

```
FindOutliers <- function(data) {
  lowerq = quantile(data)[2]
  upperq = quantile(data)[4]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq #Or use IQR(data)
  # we identify extreme outliers
  extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
  extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)
  result <- which(data > extreme.threshold.upper | data < extreme.threshold.lower)
  length(result)
}
apply(df, 2, FindOutliers)
```